# My Ubuntu 12.10 does not startup to GUI

Tags: 12.10, boot-failure

When I switch on my Laptop and chose Ubuntu to start it up. I am stuck with console only asking me for my username then for my password.

I do not know what had happened to my Ubuntu, last thing I remember is using Ubuntu Tweak, Bleach, Bleach(root).

After that I could not start an log in to the GDM.

Comment: Sounds like it might be a graphics driver problem - I've seen that. But here's something you might try before that: `sudo start lightdm`

Comment: If that doesn't work you probably need to reinstall your graphics card driver. Note: if you have an ATI graphics card and use the legacy proprietary binary from amd.com then you will run into issues installing the legacy driver on 12.10 due to kernel header changes. My advice there: `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:makson-96/fglrx && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install fglrx-legacy`

Comment: my graphics driver is nVIDIA

Comment: How can I connect to Internet in console?

Comment: @Githlar I tried "sudo start lightdm" but I got "Job is already running"

Comment: Before that my DM is GDM and now I tried "gdm" but I gote that it is not installed?!

Comment: By default (unless you installed GDM manually) Ubuntu uses lightdm. Already running eh? Try Ctrl+Alt+F7? You can connect to the internet (by this I assume you mean view web pages) in the console by installing Lynx (a console-based web browser): `sudo apt-get install lynx`

Comment: I want to connect to internet and install packages not browse websites. :) I want to do apt-get install

Comment: Got ya. The easiest way is using a wired connection, but I'm assuming you don't have that luxury (laptop). Give me a few minutes and I'll guide you on how to connect via wifi from the console (it's been a while).

Comment: I have wired network plug, do I need to plug it and I am fine with connecting to internet?

Comment: If you use a wired connection, simply plug it in and run this command: `sudo ifconfig eth0 up` (it may be eth0 or eth1). If that doesn't work you have to do the network setup manually: `ifconfig eth0 down;ifconfig eth0 address 192.168.1.X netmask 255.255.255.0` then `ifconfig eth0 up`

Comment: For wireless: `sudo iwconfig wlan0 essid "name of access point, i.e. Linksys" mode managed` if you have a key to access the network run this command as well: `sudo iwconfig wlan0 enc restricted key "NETWORK-KEY"` if the network key is ASCII (contains characters other than A-F and 0-1) prefix the key with "s:", so it would be "s:my network key" (with quotes if there are spaces of course). Follow all this up with `sudo ifconfig wlan0 up`

Comment: You mentioned it dropped you to a prompt at boot AND you're using an nVidia card. That's the same issue that my other nVidia-based computer exhibits when I need to re-compile the driver. Try this once you get networking up: `sudo stop lightdm`. If you have the nVidia driver still downloaded, go to your ~/Downloads folder and execute the installer as root (sudo). Once it completes you should boot up with a GUI again. If you don't have the driver, have a look at http://www.nvidia.com/object/unix.html and download the appropriate driver.

Comment: For the above, make sure you have `linux-headers-generic` installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not related to graphics drivers.

I have installed ia32 package with lots of dependencies. Then I remove it and I have done autoremove, too.

I figured out that gnome-shell, gdm ...etc were removed, too. So, because they where my main interface, I couldn't log in to my Ubuntu.

I have connected to internet using the network cable and installed gnome-shell

Comment: This happened to me after installing all gnome development dependencies (via "jhbuild sysdeps --install"). A combination of removing these packages then installing gdm brought my login screen back. I also had to chown ~/.Xauthority before graphical login would succeed. I learnt my lesson; now I have gnome dev packages in a VM.

Answer (score 1):

April 2013, I had the same issue, Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, also after using Ubuntu Tweak.

Here's how I fixed it :

It's almost the same as Githlar's first post.

My video card is AMD ATI Radeon HD and I used wired internet.

(1) I chose to start the login console ;
(2) then tried to reinstall video drivers : `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install fglrx` and of course, returned "yes" to install the packages to install.

This installed 3 packages : dkms, fglrx and fglrx-amdccle. An error has occured while installing dkms but it hasn't interrupted the installation.

The problem's fixed, but still have that resolution issue with lightdm login screen (unsupported by the monitor).

Hope it may help people with similar issues.

Comment: This is not an answer. It seems you've different than this question. So, you can ask your question separately as new question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem that I've seen with computers using the proprietary nVidia driver. This happens every time there's a kernel update.

Make sure you have linux-headers-generic installed: `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic`

If you've installed the drivers before and still have the last installer:

1. Make sure you are in VT1 (Ctrl+Alt+F1)
2. `sudo stop lightdm` to kill X
3. The installer is probably located in ~/Downloads: `cd ~/Downloads`
4. `sudo ./NV*run` to start the nVidia installer
5. Let it install and reboot, you should be back to a graphical desktop

If you don't have the drivers already downloaded, install Lynx (a console web browser) `sudo apt-get install lynx` and navigate to http://www.nvidia.com/object/unix.html to download the correct drivers.